# Good Fileupload plugins for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Would appreciate inputs on the best file upload plugins with support of atleast following:

1. Resizing images.
2. Flexibility of specifying the place  of storage.
3. Nice AJAX progress bar integration.
4. Multifile  uploading facility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You won't find a rails plugin that does all of that.
But with two ones, you can have what you're looking for.

Take a look at [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), which manages file upload from the server side (in ruby), the place where you want to put the file and the resizing of the images.

And take a look at [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/) (and possibly the rails plugin that goes with it, [swfupload_fu](http://github.com/alex3t/swfupload_fu/)) to have the client side and manage multiple file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

[Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) is pretty nice and here's the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)